# SQlite insert data in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm following some tutorials from youtube for sqlite crud operations. I have textfields with name, contact and address , when i hit save button it show message in console that data is saved but when i look at database it nothing appears there. My database path is correct and no errors in code but 'm confused why it isn't going. My path code is this,

```
-(void)copyandpaste{
NSArray *arr1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *str1 = [arr1 objectAtIndex:0];
strpath = [str1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"personinfo.sqlite"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:strpath]) {
    NSString *local = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"personinfo" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:local toPath:strpath error:nil];
}
NSLog(@"%@",strpath);
}
```

this method is called in appdelegate.m file,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self copyandpaste];
return YES;
}
```

I have mad NSObject class for database connection. the connection code is this,

```
-(id)init{
appdel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; //get all methods in AppDelegate
strmain = appdel.strpath;
return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getalluser:(NSString *)query{

arrdata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if (sqlite3_open([strmain UTF8String], &(database))==SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_stmt *connection;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &connection, nil)==SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(connection)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

            NSString *str12 = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(connection, 0)];  //name in first column

            NSLog(@"Checking");

            NSString *str13 = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(connection, 1)];  //contact in second column

             NSString *str14 = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(connection, 2)]; //address in third column

            [dic setObject:str12 forKey:@"name"];
            [dic setObject:str13 forKey:@"contact"];
            [dic setObject:str14 forKey:@"address"];
            [arrdata addObject:dic];
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(connection);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
return arrdata;
}
```

My save button code with query is this,

```
- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender {


NSString *saveDATA=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"insert into stuInfo values('%@','%@','%@')",txtName,txtContact,txtAddress];

dboperations *db = [[dboperations alloc ]init];
BOOL ds = [db getalluser:saveDATA];

if (ds) {
    NSLog(@"Data Saved in database");
}else{
     NSLog(@"Data is not Saved in database");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (NSString*) saveData:(NSString *)name cont:(NSString *)contacts  add:(NSString *)address
    {
const char *dbpath = [YOUR_DATA_BASE_PATH UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"=============saveData open==============");
    const char * query="insert into YOUR_TABLE_NAME(name,contacts,address) values(?,?,?);";

    sqlite3_stmt *inset_statement;

    char *errMsg;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database)!=SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Error to Open");
        return nil;
    }

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query , -1,&inset_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));
        NSLog(@"Error to Prepare");
        return nil;
    }
    //No of data to insert
    sqlite3_bind_text(inset_statement,1,[name  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(inset_statement,2,[contacts  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(inset_statement,3,[address  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    if(sqlite3_step(inset_statement)== SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        long long lastRowId = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
        NSString *rowId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)lastRowId];
        NSLog(@"Row ID of Last Inserted row %@",rowId);
        sqlite3_finalize(inset_statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"=============saveData Close==============");
        return rowId;
    }
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, query, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
        != SQLITE_OK)
    {
     NSLog(@"Failed to Insert msg in message table Error = %s",errMsg);
          sqlite3_finalize(inset_statement);
          sqlite3_close(database);
          NSLog(@"=============saveData Close==============");
          return nil;
       }
          else
           {
            sqlite3_finalize(inset_statement);
            }
          }

          NSLog(@"=============saveData Close==============");
          sqlite3_close(database);
          return nil;
          }
```

Comment: I have Written this meathod according to your condition...Just Add this...It will do your work...Hope it Helps...Thanks.

Comment: how to call this on save button click. @Neeraj Sonaro

Comment: where you have written "copyandpaste" method..write this method there only...just call this method from your save button and pass the data...only you need to give Database path and  table name as i have specified in the code.Rest every thing will be handled by my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling if there are any errors in the SQLite statements you are preparing.

The function will always return `true` because `arrdata` is never null

You need to add an`else` statements to your 
`if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &connection, nil)==SQLITE_OK)`

to show any errors...

```
NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Comment: Nothing happens still no data is going in database. @Flexicoder

Comment: no error and no data is saving in database. @Flexicoder